# Camera sometimes displaying black screen

Tags: iphone, xcode, uiimagepickercontroller

I am accessing default camera in my app.Sometimes it is displaying black screen.What is the solution for this problem?.

```
 if ([UIImagePickerController isSourceTypeAvailable:
         UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera])
    {
        imgPicker = [[UIImagePickerController alloc] init];
        imgPicker.delegate = self;
        imgPicker.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera;
//        imagePicker.mediaTypes = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:(NSString *) kUTTypeImage, nil];
        imgPicker.allowsEditing = NO;
        imgPicker.showsCameraControls = NO;
        cameraView.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
        imgPicker.cameraOverlayView = cameraView;
        [self presentModalViewController:imgPicker animated:YES];

    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the issue is with the way you present the `UIImagePickerController` instance:

```
 UIImagePickerController * imagePicker = [[UIImagePickerController alloc] init];
    imagePicker.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera;
    imagePicker.delegate = self;
    [self presentModalViewController:imagePicker animated:YES];
   // [picker release];
```

Comment: it is working fine.after taking a picture it is displying Retake,Preview and Use button.I need to change Use button as Save button.Is it possible?

Comment: So the user takes a photo then it goes to a new view with the retake, preview and save buttons

Comment: I need that view with retake,preview and save button.